# Session Expired glitch?

Tags: league-of-legends

I can't buy any skin or even RP. I keep getting the Session Expired error and I go straight back to the home page . I restarted my client many times but it's still happening. Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: probably a temporary bug.

Comment: Wish it could be gone already... I wanna buy mystery gift for my friends lol :P  How long is the bug going to take?

Comment: how should we know? have you submited a support ticket?

Comment: Yea yesterday but .. Riot takes so long =/

Comment: Reddit's /r/leagueoflegends is usually a better place to go for bug information. The format of that site lends itself better to these kind of questions.

Comment: If you want to reword this to, "How can I fix this issue?", we should have a question we might be able to help with.  "Has anyone experienced something similar?" isn't really asking us for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to a faulty Internet Explorer installment or other similar issues with Internet Explorer.

Google is your friend :)

"
Internet Explorer is a dependency of League of Legends. Many facets of League of Legends, including the store and login screen, are affected by your Internet Explorer settings. This is true even if you have a different default browser. For this reason, many common errors with the PVP.Net portion of League of Legends can be resolved by restoring your Internet Explorer settings to default."

Read more: https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201753054-Store-Error-Session-Expired-There-was-a-problem-with-your-request-